# "Device is busy", while trying to unmount with GParted

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Every time I try to unmount my hard drive, it just comes up with this error message. 
I have tried

'lsof | grep /dev/sda1' and I have tried the fuser command, but it just causes my system to restart, so I literally have no idea what to do. Please help.

I'm on ubunto 16.04 btw

Just got the fuser thing working and this came up:

1rce     2rce     3rce     4rce     5rce     7rce     8rce     9rce    10rce    11rce    12rce    13rce    15rce    16rce    17rce    18rce    19rce    20rce    21rce    22rce    23rce    25rce    26rce    27rce    28rce    29rce    30rce    31rce    32rce    33rce    34rce    35rce    36rce    37rce    38rce    39rce    42rce    43rce    45rce    46rce    47rce    48rce    63rce    64rce    65rce    66rce    67rce    68rce    69rce    70rce    71rce    72rce    73rce    74rce    75rce    76rce    77rce    78rce    79rce    80rce    81rce    82rce    83rce    84rce    85rce    86rce    87rce    88rce    92rce   106rce   107rce   126rce   148rce   149rce   150rce   151rce   152rce   153rce   154rce   155rce   156rce   162rce   163rce   164rce   165rce   172rce   173rce   174rce   202rce   204rce   205rce   217rce   233rce   238rce   245rce   246rce   278rce   291rce   365rce   506rce   520rce   528rce   667rce   669rce   670rce   678rce   679rce   682rce   685rce   710rce   715rce   716rce   718rce   719rce   777rce   780rce   782rce   794rce   797rce   815rce   834rce   850rce   856rce   928rce   985rce  1003rce  1013rce  1180rce  1182rce  1188rce  1190rce  1269rce  1277rce  1289rce  1314rce  1322rce  1328rce  1333rce  1349rce  1350rce  1354rce  1356rce  1358rce  1372rce  1376rce  1377rce  1393rce  1395rce  1399rce  1403rce  1404rce  1407rce  1417rce  1422rce  1434rce  1435rce  1436rce  1439rce  1440rce  1441rce  1442rce  1443rce  1460rce  1490rce  1497rce  1505rce  1511rce  1545rce  1607rce  1617rce  1619rce  1633rce  1644rce  1656rce  1676rce  1677rce  1684rce  1686rce  1687rce  1691rce  1719rce  1724rce  1729rce  1735rce  1741rce  1773rce  1792rce  1816rce  1823rce  1827rce  1834rce  1866rce  1899rce  1958rce  1987rce  1999rce  2000rce  2076rce  2110rce  2119rce  2133rce  2178rce  2185rce  2219rce  2233rce  2254rce  2301rce  2311rce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is /dev/sda1 your systems main partition - i.e. mounted at / ?
If so - unounting it would be a catastrophe.

Please provide some more information on your system: df -h, mount, /etc/fstab, etc

**EDIT**

There are plenty of guides on how to install linux next to windows. Just backup all your data and pick the one fitting your needs and desired linux distro:
https://www.google.de/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=howto+install+linux+next+to+windows10&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=vOmHV5WgM-PR8gfD1aG4Cg

Comment: Basically I'm trying to create a partition of that main hard drive, so I can install windows on it and have 2 operating systems. But in order to do that I need to unmount it apparently? If there is another way to do it please tell me :D

Comment: not from a running system - try booting from a live-disc and reconfigure your hard-drive's partitioning scheme from there.
But beware: this MIGHT kill some data on partitions you shrink.

Comment: btw I only got linux yesterday, so sorry for being a noob.

Comment: I tried reconfiguring through the windows 10 setup and it came up with an error saying that it couldn't find my partition. When i combined my partitions in to 1 big hard drive, I tried to create a new one from that setup disk, but instead it said that it coudln't partition it because of the format or something

Comment: Windows is "dumb" in that regard - Microsoft would not implement other filesystems in their OS.
Basically it is best to reserve space from the very start of the installation: first install linux and spare some GB on the beginning of the disk; then install windows there and reboot with the linux-disc to repair the boot manager.

Comment: In addition, it wont even let me format the hard drive so I'm pretty screwed then lol

Comment: Got it working. Created a partition somehow and installed windows on it. Then installed Ubuntu, so now I can dual boot properly now.